# A few lines from 明日你是誰

Tags: translation, grammar

Long ago, I stumbled upon [Wang Jie's `明日你是誰`](https://mojim.com/twy100018x42x7.htm) ([video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3d0eI6CJGY)). Recently, I casually sung it, and a friend asked me for a translation, and I was in trouble with a few lines. Let's see the start:

> 離別也許是簡單的一句 
>   每次說出偏要灑眼淚 
>   就像在放下也在擔起一片空虛 
>   每一個夢也伴隨

The last two lines are a bit puzzling: I know (I think) the meanings of the single words, but I can't piece together a convincing translation from them. Here is an attempt:

> "To part may be a simple.word, 
>   [But] every time I say it, I always cry, 
>   As if I were laying down [what?] and carrying a void,
>   And each [of my] dreams followed [what?]

Could someone shed light on this?

Comment: Do you have a link for the audio?

Comment: @Rodrigo the song is on Youtube. Searching for it on a mobile is not exactly easy :). When I get to my computer, if I remember, I'll add the link to the question.

Comment: @Rodrigo added. I don't know if it's on youku too, for those who have youtube blocked.

Comment: Thank you. Which spoken language is that? Taiwanese?

Comment: @Rodrigo as the video title says, it's "粤" (Cantonese).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*就像在放下也在擔起一片空虛*

就像 (it is like) 在放下 (putting down,)  也在擔起 (also like picking up) 一片空虛 (an emptiness)

- "Trying to let go of an emptiness, but this empty feeling always come back ."

*每一個夢也伴隨*

每一個夢(in every dream) 也伴隨 (it always follows me )

- "This emptiness follows me, in all of my dreams."

Comment: I think it's up to the reader who's the companion in his dreams. It may be the loneliness or the one he loved.

Comment: The two sentences are related,  the implied subject is " his heart". saying emptiness follow someone's heart, make more sense than saying a loved one follow someone's heart,  because a heart feels emptiness, and a mind think of loved one. And he just mentioned " emptiness" in the previous line, it is logical to presume it is the subject of the next line-- the subject that follow him in all his dream

Comment: But who misses a lost love uses to find it only when dreaming. Also, I don't know where you saw "heart" or "mind", but both may be 心 (so they're not necessarily opposed like you seem to imply). The only character that makes me tend to agree with you is 也 (also). But I'm not so good at Chinese to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

放下 = quit, terminate

What about this?

As if I could forget you and carrying a void.

But you are still in every of my dreams.

or

I will be your company in every of your dreams.